# YAML file doesn't get added to bin\debug on build (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a _config.yml YAML file in the root of my project.

I do in Startup.cs:

```
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()     
        .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)   
        .AddYamlFile("_config.yml");              
    Configuration = builder.Build();
```

When I build and run the project I get the following error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file '_config.yml' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documenten\Descent.Bot\bin\Debug\n
etcoreapp3.1\_config.yml'.`

Shouldn't by building the project the YAML file automatically getting added to `bin\Debug`? Is there a way to add YAML file in `bin\Debug` without me manually adding it myself?

Comment: Most files don't by default. Otherwise your output folder would get cluttered with all sorts of source files and other nonsense that you probably wouldn't want there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just right click the the file in Visual studio and click properties.
There you will see option to copy the file into output directory.

Under the hood, Visual studio is creating a None in .csproj to handle the flow

You can read it more here
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Right-click on the file in Visual Studio and set the `Build Action` to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer`.

This will add the following markup to your project (`.csproj`) file, which will tell the SDK to copy the file to the output folder when you build the application:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="_config.yml">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

You may of course also add the above to the `.csproj` file manually by editing it directly (Project->Edit Project File in Visual Studio).